# use class from namespace in php in class method

Tags: php

I'm new to php and trying to use `namespace`s for the first time and I have this crazy problem in a big php file (simplified below):

B.php:

```
namespace Logic;

class C {}
class B {}
```

A.php:

```
use Logic\C;

class A extends \BaseClass {
    public function __construct() {}
    // [...500 lines of code...]
    private function hi() { $c = new C(); }
}
```

The `hi` method gives the error: `Class 'Logic\\C' not found in A.php`

---

But if I just reference B in the constructor of A, it works as expected:

```
class A extends \Base {
    public function __construct() { $dummy = new C(); }
    // [...500 lines of code...]
    private function hi() { $c = new C(); }
}
```

When the `hi` method in the modified code above is run, there are no problems.

Can anybody think of a reasonable explanation for why this happens? Am I misusing namespaces in php?

Comment: I have no problem with your code, but you must be sure that B.php is included before using `hi()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to understand, that the `use` statement doesn't automatically include the source code file where `Logic\C` is defined. You need to use an autoloader, or manually `require_once` that file before accessing classes from that file.

---

I suggest to follow the manual about namespaces (and the examples there): http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php

Comment: There is no need to define alias with the same name as imported class.